# Text and checkbox input not aligned

Tags: html, css, forms, checkbox, alignment

I was trying to create a form, so I put some text input field and checkbox field. but it seems text fields and checkbox fields are not aligned.

I tried some online resources but in vain.

**Here is my code:**

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
    max-width: 80%;
    background-color: rgb(19, 131, 206);
    padding: 34px;
    margin: auto;
}

.container h3 {
    text-align: center;
}

input, textarea {
    width: 80%;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.container input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Login Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h3>WELCOME TO DIU QUIZ HUB</h3>
        

        <form action="index.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name">
            <input type="text" name="student_id" id="student_id" placeholder="Enter Your Student ID number">
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter Your edu mail">
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter Your Password">
            <textarea name="reason" id="reason" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Why you want to join?"></textarea>

            <input type="checkbox" name="check_box" id="check_box">Check me
            

            <br>
            <button class="btn">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>


    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am new to dev and to stackOverflow too.

Comment: Try to put your code using snippet here or try codepen.io and paste the link here so we can see the results of your css and html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set the width - 80% for all inputs, including checkbox. So additionally you need to stylise the checkbox like that:

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
  width:auto;
  margin:-2px 5px 0 0;
}
```

Thus you'll reset its width and add some helpful margins

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @GL.awog

```
.container input[type="checkbox"]{
    width:auto;
    margin:-2px 5px 0 0;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

this helped <3